# Selenium python - How to scroll to text that its parent element contains class="min"

Tags: python, selenium

### How can I scroll to text that only contains min class

```
<div>
   <div class="item filter_2 firstPart">
       <div class="date">16/10/2018</div>
       <div class="time">04:00</div>
       <div class="event">Ningbo, China</div>
       <div class="subevent">HE, Yecong - Kecmanovic, Miomir</div>
       <div class="odds">
          <div class="odd" idq="2998675069">
             <div class="tq">1HH</div>
             <div class="value">8.00</div>
          </div>
          <div class="odd min" idq="2998675068">
             <div class="tq">2HH</div>
             <div class="value">1.03</div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I will like to scroll to text if min class is present

Here is what i have tried:

```
new_text = ['2.10', '2.15', '2.20', '2.25', '2.30', '2.35', '2.40', 
                 '2.45', '2.50', '2.55', '2.60', '2.65', '2.70',
                 '2.75', '2.80', '2.85', '2.90', '2.95', '3.10']

for text in new_text:
    if text in driver.page_source:
       parent = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".odd.min")
       child = parent.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='value' 
               and text()='" + text + "']")
       if child:
               print(text)
               element = child
               driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', 
                 element)
               driver.save_screenshot('lo7.png')
               break
       else:
               print("No odd found")
               continue
```

The problem about this code is that it also scrolls to text that does not contain min class

Image file:
[image: odd]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please add some code to the question?

Comment: Why do you need to scroll to that text?

Comment: @JeffC, i need confirmation that the text exist page and it's is of min class

Comment: @jamesmaduka Does the class `min` always comes along with class `odd`? Or along class `even` as well? If so, would you consider to scroll to the first element with class `min`?

Answer (score 1):

```
//div[@class='odd min']/div[@class='tq']/text()
```

u can try this xpath expression to get the value of "2HH".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your XPath locator. You are locating `parent` and then starting there using an XPath searching only for children using `parent.find_element_by_xpath("//div...`. If you want an XPath to start from the `parent` context, you need to add a `.` at the start, e.g. `".//div[@class='value' and ..."`. If you don't include that `.`, then your XPath looks at the entire page, as you discovered.

There is a better way to do this... don't print a bunch of screenshots, just pull the odds that you want and compare them to your desired list.

```
values_from_page = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".odd.min > div.value") # all odds elements from the page
odds = (e.text for e in values_from_page if e.is_displayed()) # filter down to only visible elements and get the text
print(odds)

new_text = ['2.10', '2.15', '2.20', '2.25', '2.30', '2.35', '2.40', 
            '2.45', '2.50', '2.55', '2.60', '2.65', '2.70',
            '2.75', '2.80', '2.85', '2.90', '2.95', '3.10']
missing_odds = new_text.difference(odds) # filter down to any new_text odds missing on page
print(missing_odds)
```

This is untested code but should be pretty close. With my code, it should run WAY faster because you are only scraping the page once (and only once) instead of scraping twice per item in `new_text` plus scrolling the page and taking a screenshot for each one.

When you take a screenshot, someone has to look at it to verify. That takes manual work and time... avoid this whenever possible. Let the automation do the validation for you and only report when something is wrong/missing. If `missing_odds` is empty `len(x) = 0`, then all the items in `new_text` were found. Anything that is printed, was missing from the page.

Hopefully that helps get you started in the right direction.